# Extract value from XML file using shell script

Tags: linux, text-processing, xml

I have file `filestore.xml` from which I need to extract `/local/armdata/data/filestore1`, `/local/armdata/data/filestore2`.

```
grep binariesDir filestore.xml
    <binariesDir>/local/armdata/data/filestore1</binariesDir>
    <binariesDir>/local/armdata/data/filestore2</binariesDir>
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: grep binariesDir filestore.xml
        <binariesDir>/local/armdata/data/filestore1</binariesDir>
        <binariesDir>/local/armdata/data/filestore2</binariesDir>

Comment: Please don't add information in the comments, edit the question, especially if it needs formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`XMLStarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```
xml sel -t -v '//binariesDir' filestore.xml
```

on Ubuntu with `xmlstarlet` package installed, I need to use this:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//binariesDir' filestore.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed`.

```
sed -nre 's:^.*<binariesDir>(.*)</binariesDir>.*$:\1:p' filestore.xml
```

This handles both the searching for binariesDir and extracting the value between `<binariesDir>` and `</binariesDir>`.